# Wrapping every word in a div causes performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a one page website with nearly 5000 words as text to give a specific animation effect i need to wrap every word in a div tag with a class like this.

```
<div class="word"> word</div>
```

That results in too many `div`s (too many elements in DOM).
I completely understand that it is ridiculous to have 5000 elements in DOM

is there any other way it is possible?

This is the effect I am trying to achieve:

```js
$('body').children('.word').each(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 500);
});
```

```css
.word {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word">
  hello,
</div>
<div class="word">
  how
</div>
<div class="word">
  are
</div>
<div class="word">
  you
</div>
<div class="word">
  doing
</div>
```

**EDIT:** **Is this a better way**

http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/cxvuq96v/

Comment: Why do you need this behaviour? As you've seen there is a finite number of elements you can place in the DOM before you get performance degradation, although 5000 div elements is a little ridiculous.

Comment: Try to consider a canvas animation instead

Comment: Consider what you have just asked, doesnt it sound just a little bit ridiculous in your head? 5000 div elements?

Comment: Consider wrapping groups or sentences, but really consider if this is a good idea. (hint: it's not.)

Comment: Use less words per page? :$

Comment: Can you explain in words the effect you are expecting to achieve

Comment: @surajck i added a snippet of the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is low perfomance of `$.animate`. It makes insane number of DOM updates (thousands per second) making your website slow.

You should use CSS Animations or CSS transitions that are executed with support of GPU and without DOM updates.

You can create code like this:

```
$('body').children('.word').each(function() {
  $(this).style({transition: 'opacity '+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 500) +'s'});
  $(this).addClass('visible');
});
```

And add following code to CSS file:

```
 .visible {
      opacity: 1;
  }
```

Comment: True, but with 5000 DOM elements you're pushing it regardless.

Comment: 5000 elements is like nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/Ginden/wm024254/3/embedded/result/  - 5000 DOM elements can be created and inserted in less than 30ms on my laptop.

Comment: BTW - animation, even GPU boosted is quite slow. It can be overcome by reducing number of elements animated **at once** or using canvas.

But issue isn't number of DOM elements (this SO page have 3339), but unnecesary operations on them.

Comment: 5000 DOM elements being created, yes. But 5000 DOM elements being animated all at once is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your example, my original suggestion doesn't give the effect you're demonstrating there.

I think achieving that with 5000 words will be more tricky, but creating 5000 elements on the DOM and animating them all isn't the way!

I'd suggest instead of having every element coming in at different times, make it seem as though they are.

Consider creating 10 (or maybe more) elements on the DOM, exactly positioned with the words laid out in a way that makes it look like a single complete sentence (or however you want to structure the content).

Then, apply the random fade in effect to those DOM elements. That way, so long as you have the words randomly spread between each DOM element, it will appear as though they are all coming in at different times.

Experiment with how many different DOM elements you need to make the effect seem random, whilst not overloading the DOM.

Comment: i want to aply a jQuery animate to every word with a different 'time'. is that possible any other way.

Comment: thanks for your response Matt, But what i am trying to do is fade-in different words in different random time. in the above example you posted, the whole text fade-in simultaneously, which can be easily achived by animating paragraphs instead.

Comment: Not if you put spacing between the words. So for example, in one div have "The        brown        jumps" and in another "       quick       fox". Then absolute position them over each other to look like a single paragraph. You would probably want to write some code to position the text for you and create your initial structure.